# Extract pixels buffer from Image Gdi+

Tags: graphics, scale, gdi+, pixel

I would like to extract pixel buffer from `Gdiplus::Image`
Here is my code :

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN), BPP4 * GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), PixelFormat32bppARGB, data);

Gdiplus::Image *pThumbnail = bitmap.GetThumbnailImage(mWidthResolutionSelected, mHeightResolutionSelected, NULL, NULL);
```

How to get pixel buffer after the scale with `GetThumbnailImage` from `pThumbnail` ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cast pThumbnail to a Bitmap* and then you use the LockBits method to get a BitmapData object, which contains the Scan0 field, which is a pointer to the pixel data. Don't forget to call UnlockBits when you're done.

Comment: Thanks it worked! But I'm facing a problem.. Why the image has some wrong pixels on display ?

Comment: Without seeing what's wrong, I cannot tell, but you need to be aware that the lines may be padded to aling on 4 byte boundaries. The Stride property is there to help you locatde the start of each line and skip over the padding.

Comment: I'm taking a screenshot of my desktop then I get the byte buffer (rgba) in 1920x1080 resolution.
I pass this byte buffer to the function GetThumbnailImage in order to scale it  in 1280x720. When I draw the image again I have wrong pixels on some windows of the desktop.. For example : the file explorer instead of having white pixels I have black pixels after the scale... That's so weird...